# SQL: To obtain single record for each CourseId

Tags: sql-server

I'm naive to SQL...pls help me with my below query:

I have a table named `Course` as shown below:

```
 Key  CourseName   CourseId   IsCurrentVersion  

  0    Course_1      A         0
  1    Course_1      A         0
  2    Course_1      A         1
  3    Course_2      B         0
  4    Course_2      B         0
  5    Course_3      C         1
  6    Course_4      D         0
  7    Course_5      E         0
  8    Course_5      E         0
  9    Course_6      F         1
 10    Course_6      F         1
 11    Course_6      F         1
 12    Course_7      G         1
 13    Course_7      G         0
 14    Course_7      G         0
```

I want the below result set:

```
 CourseName   CourseId   IsCurrentVersion

  Course_1      A          1
  Course_2      B          0
  Course_3      C          1
  Course_4      D          0
  Course_5      E          0
  Course_6      F          1
  Course_7      G          1
```

For records having same CourseId; IsCurrentVersion having 1 should be preferred to 0. Single records should also get displayed in output irrespective of their IsCurrentVersion values.

Database is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CourseName, CourseId, IsCurrentVersion
FROM Course AS A
WHERE IsCurrentVersion = (SELECT MAX(IsCurrentVersion)
                          FROM Course AS B
                          WHERE A.CourseId = B.CourseId)
GROUP BY CourseName, CourseID, IsCurrentVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you are looking for, assuming the only values for IsCurrentVersion are 1 and 0.

```
SELECT CourseName, CourseId, MAX(IsCurrentVersion)
FROM Course
GROUP BY CourseName, CourseID
```

If the IsCurrentVersion column is a bit and not an integer, use this instead.

```
SELECT CourseName, CourseId, MAX(CASE WHEN IsCurrentVersion = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Course
GROUP BY CourseName, CourseID
```

Comment: I'm getting NULL in CourseId for all records.